# Print points with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have this program where I print some points from a CSV file I have but when the frame appears it is already sketched.

How can the frame be blank at start and then watch the sketching process? I know I should put a timer but for start I have to do this without a timer.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lesson1 extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Lesson1();
    }

    public Lesson1() {
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(new DrawStuff(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class DrawStuff extends JComponent {

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D graph2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            graph2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
            graph2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            File file = new File("data.csv");
            List < String > lines;

            try {
                lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                for (String line: lines) {
                    String[] array = line.split(",");
                    double a = Double.parseDouble(array[2]);
                    double b = Double.parseDouble(array[3]);
                    int x = (int) a;
                    int y = (int) b;
                    graph2.fillOval(x * 5, y * 5, 3, 3);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I know i should put a timer*: so the answer is in the question.

Comment: Indeed, i editted the question for what i really want to do

Comment: You won't be able to see the points draw themselves one by one without any kind of timer. Unless you add a button which adds the next point each time you click it. Then the timer will be the user of the app.

Comment: So the frame will be blank at start and then instally sketched? Thanks i didnt think of this very carefully